# Why QTreeView does not show the data?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I have a trouble with *QTreeView*. When I run this code `ui->treeView` does not show the data:

```
QStandardItemModel paramList;
QStandardItem itemroot("cats");
QStandardItem item1("cats");
QStandardItem item2("dogs");
QStandardItem item3("rats");
itemroot.setChild(0,&item1);
itemroot.setChild(1,&item2);
itemroot.setChild(2,&item3);
paramList.setItem(0,&itemroot);
ui->treeView->setModel(&paramList);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: If you want to get real help, you should first post a minimal & complete code sample that doesn't work as you expected. Otherwise you'll just get pointed to the documentation

Comment: Indeed, please provide us with a bit more information if possible. In any case, perhaps this link could provide you with some pointers: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/modelview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the header (private):

```
QStandardItemModel paramList;
```

in the .cpp

```
ui->treeView->setModel(&paramList);
QStandardItem *itemroot = new QStandardItem("cats");
QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem("cats");
QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem("dogs");
QStandardItem *item3 = new QStandardItem("rats");
itemroot->setChild(0,item1);
itemroot->setChild(1,item2);
itemroot->setChild(2,item3);
paramList.setItem(0,itemroot);
```